# Force HTTPS on certain URLs

Tags: apache, http, mod-rewrite, https

We have a requirement where we need to write two rewrite rules in apache.

```
Add new Apache rule http://*.test.com -> https://*.test.com
Add new Apache rule http://*.test.com/home/ -> https://*.test.com/home/
```

How can I achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} test.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1
```

This should apply to http://*.test.com/* .
You have to put this into your virtual host configuration or a .htaccess file.